# NameVirtualHost bad behavior on 2 IPs and 3 DocumentRoot

Tags: virtualhost, apache

I have the next apache virtualhosts and NameVirtualHost settings:

```
NameVirtualHost 10.100.106.89

<VirtualHost 10.100.106.89>
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html/dev/novared_soporte/branches/v0.3/soporte
        ServerName 10.100.106.89
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost 10.100.106.89>
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html/phpmyadmin
        ServerName 10.100.106.89/phpmyadmin
        ServerAlias 10.100.106.89/pma
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost 10.100.106.90>
        ServerName 10.100.106.90
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html
</VirtualHost>
```

When I try to reach: `10.100.106.89` I can get to the site that I need: `/var/www/html/dev/novared_soporte/branches/v0.3/soporte`

but when I try to reach `10.100.106.89/phpmyadmin` I actually get this error on error_log.txt (httpd logs):

`[Thu Jun 28 12:12:59 2012] [error] [client 10.100.103.31] File does not exist: /var/www/html/dev/novared_soporte/branches/v0.3/soporte/phpmyadmin`

I still cant get where is the mistake. By the way, `10.100.106.90` is working properly, at least for its `DocumentRoot /var/www/html`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`10.100.106.89/phpmyadmin` not a valid ServerName. It needs to be either an IP address or a hostname/domain name. You don't put paths in there.

Use a `<Location>` block in the first virtual server instead.

Comment: Actually Alias would be better: add line `Alias /phpmyadmin /var/www/html/phpmyadmin` in the first VirtualHost.